# Alloy createController is not released from memory

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Recently I have been doing some memory analysis on one of my application. The application is made for Android platform. For two of the screens, I am observing that there is a leak.

No validate, I removed all of my code and kept only $.screenName.open() call on both the controllers and they way of calling them is:

```
Alloy.createController(screenToLaunch, payloadJson);
```

Inside the respective controllers, the open() call was present. I use DDMS and do a heap analysis.

Before opening Controller A, I pressed the cause GC several time to get a stable allocated reading. Once done I launch Controller A and press the back button to close it. Now when I click on cause GC several times, there is a difference of 60KB, everytime.

I am not storing the createController reference in any global variable. Any idea as to why it is behaving in such manner?

**Updated**:
[image: HPROF Difference]

Above is the HPROF difference between opening and closing of the controller. I am not using any DB calls, yet I see there are many DB related calls being made. I think it might be that the framework is using those calls for its internal functioning.

Comment: Can you share code of this as it could be due to many reasons ?

Comment: Hi Prashant, the JS code contains just the call $.controllerName.open() and the XML contains a scrollview with multiple 2 inner views.

Comment: Share some screenshots and your environment configurations as 60KB difference does not seems too much and could be dependent on device or your development environment because I am sure that you already are aware of memory clean-up ways. Are you using Mac OS or Windows or Linux..?

Comment: I am yet to run XCode Instruments on the code to try and pin point if any I am not clearing up any proxy and it is lingering around for which the leak is occurring. I am doing the development on Mac OS. As for GC, I know that it is system specific, so after pressing the GC button for several time, I wait for few minutes before taking my reading. Do you need th screenshots for the monitor (android tool) with the reading?

Comment: I have added the HPROF difference between the two states and the object difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this [architecture](https://github.com/juanagu/AlloyArchitectureTemplate/blob/master/AlloyDefault/app/controllers/architecture/window.js) for controllers (UI.Windows) and works very well.

- Open window : Alloy.createController('name_controller').getView().open();

[Cleaning up Alloy controllers](http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/18/cleaning-up-alloy-controllers/)

Comment: So instead of calling win.open() inside the name_controller, you do getVoew().open(). Does it help is releasing the controller object once I press the back key and close name_controller? May be I can modify the code and see if this works.

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Right, that is what I though so. I am even setting the variable to null which stores the reference to the controller. I guess I need to use XCode instruments to figure it out or may be need to do a HPROF analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is my cleanup method for all controllers and widgets:

someview.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {},
    data = {};

data.button = Alloy.createController('button',{
    title:'button'
}).getView();

 $.view.cleanup = function() {

    $.destroy();

    $.off();

    data.button.cleanup();

    $ = data = args = null;
};
```

button.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {},
    data = {};

data.click = function() { ... };

$.view.addEventListener('click',data.click);

$.view.cleanup  = function() {

    $.destroy();

    $.off();

    $.view.removeEventListener('click',data.click);

    $ = data = args = null;
};
```

I've created a global function, to call the cleanup method and remove it's content on every children of the controllers:

**UPDATE**

added delete operator and try statement

```
exports.unset = function(view) {

    if(view) {

        if(view.children && view.children.length) {

            for(var i in view.children) try { util.unset(view.children[i]);
            } catch(e) {}

            view.removeAllChildren();
        }

        if(view.views && view.views.length) for(var i = view.views.length; i > 0; i--) if(view.views[i-1]) {

            if(view.removeView) view.removeView(i-1);

            try { util.unset(view.views[i-1]);
            } catch(e) {}
        }

        if(view.cleanup) try { view.cleanup();
        } catch(e) {}

        view = null;

        delete view;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have put in the $.off and $.destroy code. But still it retains the objects. I need to try and create a sample application out of it and then test it.

Comment: when you remove the view or run the cleanup method, it still exists according to my project logs, after setting the view equals to null, I can't no longer use it or its methods, but I think that its only removed from memory after garbage collection on android, on iOS I've heard about ARC, but I'm not sure what that is. I would like to understand better this 'Memory Management' questions, since my biggest app uses only one Window, but changes it content a lot, with a large number of views and widgets, that code was my best approach.

Comment: This is the same approach that I follow. After removing the views, I set them explicitly to null. As for GC in Android, it will trigger when there is a crunch in memory or whenever the GC algo thinks to trigger it. Another interesting snippet I found in your code is, setting $ to null and args to null. Are these two necessary. Won't it be done by the framework itself?

Comment: I don't know if the framework will do that, but just in case, as I use all my controller methods and properties inside the 'var data = {};' and I'm always using the arguments, at the end of all my controllers, I use that: '$ = data = args = null;'

Comment: I guess it will be better to assign the args variable to null. Will make the change and see if that helps and keep this thread posted.

Comment: After setting some object properties to null or undefined, running 'Object.keys(myObj).length' returns the same value as that property still exists, so after I set it to null, at that 'unset' global function I've added: delete view;

Comment: I've updated the unset function in my answer: added delete operator and try statement